# What is wrong with my RESTORE procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use Toad Freeware (my SSMS is totally broken) for the following restore command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2016
FROM DISK = 'C:\Database\MSSQL\Samples\AdventureWorks2016CTP3.bak'
```

The response is:

```
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.DSMAIN\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2016CTP3_Data.mdf" failed with the operating system error 21(The device is not ready.).
```

I don't even have a `D` drive. I suspect the original database files were stored on a `D` drive, but what do I do now?

Comment: You need to choose RESTORE WITH MOVE: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I had found that, and it still didn't work - then I found the magic 'Restore' menu command that did everything for me :-)

Comment: You should have generated the script from the Restore pop-up box (instead of just clicking OK) – that way the menu command would have done for you even more.

Comment: I didn't see one, otherwise you could be sure I would have.

Comment: The Script option is in the top left of the Restore dialog, for future reference.

Comment: That script option is for SSMS, OP states he is using Toad Freeware, not sure if script option is present in that software?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up partitioning a D: drive, then it worked. Funny thing is that after it restored, D: drive was empty. :o